# Can't run curl command from within Elixir with System.cmd

Tags: curl, command, system, elixir

I'm just trying to use Elixir to run a curl command with a specific format.

```
$ curl -w "@config/curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s "http://wordpress.com/"
0.004, 0.017, 0.000, 0.017, 0.000, 0.029, 0.029
```

Running the command directly from the terminal works fine.

---

This is what I'm trying to do in Elixir:

```
args = ["-w config/curl-format.txt", "-o /dev/null", "-s", "http://wordpress.com"]
result = System.cmd("curl", args, [])
```

But I get:

```
{" config/curl-format.txt", 23}
```

And not the same result as above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `System.cmd` invocation is equivalent (in shell syntax) to:

```
curl "-w config/curl-format.txt" "-o /dev/null" -s http://wordpress.com
```

You need to pass in `-w`, `config/curl-format.txt`, `-o`, and `/dev/null` as different arguments. You also missed the `@` in `@config/curl-format.txt`. This should work:

```
args = ["-w", "@config/curl-format.txt", "-o", "/dev/null", "-s", "http://wordpress.com"]
result = System.cmd("curl", args, [])
```